# How to use (PHP)foreach to update my javascript timetable with the recordes from my database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I am making a timetable with php and javascript and if each time i add a (name,time,date..) i want to update my javascript timetable

i am using phpmyadmin for my database and the timetable is gantt and  from am4charts

this is the php:

```
$query =  "SELECT Nom FROM registre";
$resultat = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$data = array();
//$chart_data = '';
//while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)) 
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultat)>0){
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat))    
{
    $data2[] = $row;
}

}

//print_r($data);

foreach ($data2[0] as $data2) {
  echo $data2;
}
```

this is javascript:

```
chart.data = [
{
name:"<?php echo $data2; ?>",
fromDate: "2018-01-01 08:00",
toDate: "2018-01-01 10:00",
color: colorSet.getIndex(0).brighten(0)
},
];
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "name";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
```

Comment: _Side note:_ You're not using PHPMyAdmin as your database. PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL databases. Your application is using MySQL, not PHPMyAdmin,

Comment: You may have to use either AJAX with some regular time interval or a Socket program to automatically update it.
Or, with the hit of add button, you have to trigger an AJAX, then wrap your chart code within response code, to update it.
Do some research to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

First, what errors are you getting or what is the result and how it differs from your wanted result?
After some testing I think that you're getting the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error. In that case try:

```
foreach ($data2 as $datarow) {
     echo $datarow;
}
```

Let me know if this was the fix you were looking for!